# awk match substring in column from 2 files

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following two files (real data is tab-delimited instead of semicolon):
`input.txt`

```
Astring|2042;MAR0303;foo1;B
Dstring|2929;MAR0283;foo2;C
```

`db.txt` ***updated***

```
TG9284;Astring|2042|morefoohere_foo_foo
TG9281;Cstring|2742|foofoofoofoofoo Dstring|2929|foofoofoo
```

So, column1 of `input.txt`is a substring of column2 of `db.txt`. Only two "fields" separated by `|` is important here.

I want to use awk to match these two columns and print the following (again in tab-delimited form):

```
Astring|2042;MAR0303;foo1;B;TG9284
Dstring|2929;MAR0283;foo2;C;TG9281
```

This is my code:

```
awk -F'[\t]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1}$1 in a {print $0"\t"$1}' input.txt db.txt
```

***EDIT***
column2 of `db.txt` contains strings of column1 of `input.txt`, delimited by a space. There are many more strings in the real example than shown in the short excerpt.

Comment: And `db.txt` really has a pipe after that "`$2`", not a semicolon?

Comment: yes. The file has two columns, the second has a kind of identifier that is composed of some string - pipe - 4 digit number. That part should be matched.

Comment: @anubhava I want the `TG####`

Comment: clarify `TG9281;Cstring|2742|foofoofoofoofoo Dstring|2929|foofoofoo` layout and intent.

Comment: Use `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1` to avoid awk trying to match lines from `input.txt` from the alreaudy examined lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{
   split($2, b, "|"); a[b[1] "|" b[2]]=$1; next}
$1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' db.txt input.txt

Astring|2042    MAR0303 foo1    B   TG9284
Dstring|2929    MAR0283 foo2    C   TG9281
```

---

**EDIT:**

As per your comment you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {
  a[$2]=$1; next} {for (i in a) if (index(i, $1)) print $0, a[i]}' db.txt input.txt

Astring|2042    MAR0303 foo1    B   TG9284
Dstring|2929    MAR0283 foo2    C   TG9281
```

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in the `db.txt`. The substring can be _anyhwere_ in column2

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Why do you read in the `db.txt` first? I got used to doing the opposite...

Comment: I just found it easier to deal with a smaller 2 column file in first block.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the semicolons, you can replace with the tabs:

```
$ awk -F\; '
NR==FNR {                     # hash the db file
    a[$2]=$1
    next
}
{
    for(i in a)               # for each record in input file
       if($1~i) {             # see if $1 matches a key in a
           print $0 ";" a[i]  # output
           # delete a[i]      # delete entry from a for speed (if possible?)
           break              # on match, break from for loop for speed
       }
}' db input                   # order order
Astring|2042;MAR0303;foo1;B;TG9284
Dstring|2929;MAR0283;foo2;C;TG9281
```

For each record in `input` script matches the $1 against every entry in `db`, so it's slow. You can speed it up by adding a `break` to the `if` and `delete`ing matching entry from `a` (if your data allows it).